# Is it logical to use <header>, <main>, <footer> tag inside an <article> tag?

Tags: html, validation, markup

Recently I've come to notice some people use `<header>`, `<main>`, `<footer>` tag, inside an `<article>` tag to determine the parts of an article. I want to  know if this is right. Is it helpful for the search engine to optimize?

trying to find an answer.

Comment: From the seo tag. Note: General SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it's "right" or not is answered by the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-article-element), which states that the allowed content for an `article` element is [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#flow-content-2). This includes all the tags that you mentioned (`header`, `main`, `footer`).

There are however limitations when it comes to the use of the `main` element as it has a distinct set of allowed ancestor elements, which does not include `article`.

The specification has an explicit example of an `article` with `header` and `footer` elements, yet no `main` element.

Whether it's helpful for search engines is an entirely different matter, and feels like a question that cannot be answered without gathering some evidence comparing the behavior of various search engines.